# Can vuejs use in v-if

Tags: arrays, vue.js

I want to use 'in' syntax in Vue.js v-if like Python.
However, it doesn't seem to be working.

If I want to know if an element is in an array, how can I edit the following code?

```html
<div id="app">
    <ol>
        <li v-for="site in sites" v-if="site.name in fs">
            {{ site.name }}
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>

<script>
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            sites: [
                { name: 'Runoob' },
                { name: 'Google' },
                { name: 'Taobao' }
            ],
        },
        fs: [
            'Google'
        ]
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Your image link is not working. But please consider using a code sample instead.

Comment: Make a computed property or method which returns true/false: `v-if="isInArray(myDataProp)"`

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, so, the keyword [`in`](http://Yeah,%20so,%20the%20keyword%20%60in%60%20in%20javascript%20is%20only%20used%20to%20iterate%20over%20an%20array,%20not%20to%20check%20if%20an%20element%20is%20contained%20into%20it.%20%20You%20can%20use%20[%60Array.some%60][1]%20instead.%20In%20your%20example:%20%20%20%20%20%20v-if=%22fs.some(e%20=%3E%20site.name%20===%20e)%20%20%20%20%20[1]:%20https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some?v=control) in javascript is only used to iterate over an array, or to check for index value, not to check if an element is contained into it.

You can use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/indexOf) instead. In your example:

```
v-if="fs.indexOf(site.name) !== -1"
```